# syntax for multi-line object properties doesn't allow key/value on first line?

Tags: coffeescript

The coffeescript parser is telling me that this is not okay:

```
{ one: 1,
  two: 2
}
```

But this is:

```
{
  one: 1,
  two: 2
}
```

Is this a straightforward syntax rule, or a side-effect of something else going on in this example?

Comment: Works if you don't indent the `two:2` part, also works if you do it all on one line. I'm guessing that CS is getting confused by what it thinks is a double indent.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee-script is white space sensitive, and has optional tokens to enhance readability.

Without looking into the internals of the parser, my understanding is that coffee-script is stripping out optional parts during parsing phase - something like...

```
# original...
x = { one: 1,
  two: 2
}

# ignore curlies, leaving...
x = one: 1,
  two: 2

# remove comma leaving incorrectly indented code...
x = one: 1
  two: 2
```

By writing in white space sensitive style from the offset...

```
# new style
x = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2
}

# remove the curlies
x =
  one: 1,
  two: 2

# remove the comma, and nice clear whitespace sensitive definition remains...
x =
  one: 1
  two: 2
```